# Why does HttpCachePolicy default value (Private) causes server to cache responses?

Tags: .net, iis, web-applications, cache-control

In my web application (.Net 4.7.2) running on IIS (8.5 on a win2012) I had this code line:

```
Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

at:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
```

on my master page code behind.

I expected that by removing it, the default value ([Private](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcacheability?view=netframework-4.8)) wouldn't cause to cache responses from server but it did. Diferent users started getting responses from the server that were cached (because they were from previous requests to the same page).

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The default cache-control header is : Private

A cache mechanism may cache this page in a private cache and resend it only to a single client. This is the default value. Most proxy servers will not cache pages with this setting.

First, make sure you imported the master page in all the pages because you added the no-cache code in your master page.

if it still not work for you you could use the IIS HTTP response header feature to clear the client cache:

1)Open IIS Manager, select your site.

2)Double click the HTTP Response Headers from the middle pane

[image]

3)In the HTTP Response Headers pane, click Set Common Headers... in the Actions pane.

4)In the Set Common HTTP Response Headers dialog box, check the box to expire Web content, select the option to expire immediately, and then click OK.

[image]

You could also refer below article for more detail information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time.

I do have the master page setup in all my pages and the common headers feature at IIS also set as you posted.

The issue i'm struggling with, is that this "resend it only to a single client." did not happened. The default cache-control header (Private) caused server responses to be cached and different accesses (differente sessions on IIS) got the same cached response from the server.. isn't this weird?

I can't figure out why has this happened.

Comment: @joaopintocruz could you please share your response header snapshot?